# Splitting a large project into separate projects - angular dependencies

Tags: angularjs, node.js, browserify, webpack

Let's say that I have a large project written in AngularJS and node. There are discreet "modules" within this project, say a screen designer, a chat room and a workflow designer.

So it makes sense to split these three components into their own git repo.

However, I now face a problem

- Project A (screen designer) needs ng-drag
- Project B (workflow) needs angular-ui
- Project C (chat) needs angular-websocket

How / where do I create a file that serves all of the files from the projects in the correct order and maintains the correct dependencies for injection etc.

Do I need to create a project D that is merely a placeholder to include A,B and C? There is also the possibility that each project may be used on it's own or as a combination of projects (A and C for example)

I've been looking at webpack and browsify but can't yet get my head around  some of the concepts

I would appreciate any help or insight .. thanks !

Comment: thanks for the edit - I shouldn't have been so lazy and done that myself. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of workspace you can have something like

```
-ProjectA
 _index.js contains require('ng-drag')
-ProjectB
 _index.js contains require('angular-ui')
-ProjectC
 _index.js contains require('angular-websocket')
main.js
```

main.js

```
  require('./ProjectA/_index)
  require('./ProjectB/_index)
  require('./ProjectC/_index)
```